# Cannot use 'Int32' before it is declared C#

Tags: c#, dataset

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public class StockMainDL
{
    string conString = "Data Source=KamranAhmed\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=City_Car;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand com;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;

    public StockMainDL()
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        con.Open();
    }


    public List<StockMain> GetChartData(string mode)
    {
        List<StockMain> stockMain = new List<StockMain>();

        string query = "SELECT * FROM StockMain";
        com = new SqlCommand(query);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        da.Fill(ds);


        foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {

            stockMain.Add(new StockMain(Int32.Parse(item["Stid"]), Int32.Parse(item["Vrno"]), Int32.Parse(item["Vrnoa"]), Convert.ToDateTime(item["Vrdate"]), item["Party_id"].ToString(), item["Bilty_No"].ToString(), Convert.ToDateTime(item["Bilty_Date"]), item["Received_By"].ToString(), item["Transporter_id"].ToString(), item["Remarks"].ToString(), Int32.Parse(item["Year_Srno"]), item["EType"].ToString(), Int32.Parse(item["NAmount"]), Int32.Parse(item["UId"]), Int32.Parse(item["VrNo"]), Int32.Parse(item["OrderVrNo"]), Int32.Parse(item["Freight"]), item["Party_Id_Co"].ToString(), Int32.Parse(item["SaleBillNo"]), float Discp, float Discount, Int32.Parse(item["Currency_Id"]), float Expense, Int32.Parse(item["Company_Id"]), item["Vehicle_Id"].ToString(), Convert.ToBoolean(Item["IsEditted"]), Convert.ToBoolean(Item["IsNew"]), Convert.ToBoolean(Item["IsDeleted"])));

        }

        return stockMain;
    }
}
```

Above is the code that I'm using to first get the dataset from the database and the transform this dataset to a List and then return this list. The problem I'm having is, inside the foreach loop it gives this error "Cannot use 'Int32' before it is declared", I tried to use Convert.ToInt32() it gives the same error for "Convert".

Can anybody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are using `Item` instead of `item` inside that FOR loop for few parameters. That is throwing you this error. Remember the variables used are case-sensitive

Comment: Well spotted @Sachin. I had to scroll all the way across to see what you were talking about! :)